# How do I make the header tag go on top and to the center

Tags: css, reactjs

So I am really confused as to why my h2 tag keeps getting sided with my card panel here. I want to put a header on top of the card. Here is the layout code and the index.js. Please tell me what changes i can make in order to achieve this. I also included the screenshot of the problem

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: #ffbe76;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

p {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

here is the index.js

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout"
import Card from "../components/Card/Card"

const Homepage = () => {
  return (
    
    <Layout>
      <h2> HEADER</h2>
      <Card />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Homepage
```

[image: Here is where it keeps showing up. i want the header on top]

Comment: please snippet your code

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you share the styles and template of `Layout` component?